How to wrap a paragraph in code, issues in its implementation?
I am doing a job in vim, it has been very effective for me. But there are things that I still don't understand. Because I am doing bilingual work in columns using latex, I have to wrap paragraphs in these two codes:
\begin{otherlanguage}{american}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{paragraphs 1}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{spanish}paragraphs 2\switchcolumn*

What I am looking for is that, being in normal mode, if the cursor is in paragraph 1, select this paragraph, wrap the content in one of the two codes and, if possible, the cursor remains, after having done the above, at the beginning of the next paragraph.
I have tried with this code, but it selects not only paragraph 1, but all the paragraphs that follow it before an empty paragraph. And it also duplicates the content of all these paragraphs.
" Mapping for the 'q' key to perform the described action
nnoremap q :call InsertLatexBlock()<CR>

function! InsertLatexBlock()
  " Move to the beginning of the paragraph
  normal! {

  " Select the entire paragraph (only the current paragraph)
  normal! vip

  " Copy the selected text to the register
  normal! y

  " Get the content of the register (the selected paragraph)
  let paragraph = getreg('"')

  " Create the LaTeX block with the paragraph inside \grande{}
  let latex_block = '\\begin{otherlanguage}{american}\\selectlanguage{greek}\\grande{' . paragraph . '}\\end{otherlanguage}\\switchcolumn'

  " Delete the original paragraph
  normal! "_d

  " Paste the LaTeX block and the original text
  normal! i
  execute "normal! A" . latex_block

  " Return to normal mode for the next action
  normal! }

endfunction


How's the second line, the one with "spanish" related to your question? How's the tagged vim-latex plugin related? You don't seem to use it. Also, did you by any chance use an AI tool to write that function? Not a problem in itself but the pattern of obvious comment-line of code strikes me. The last comment is off, see :help } to understand why.

I suspect that what you call paragraph is only a line return where for Vim it is two consecutive line return (an empty line separation). Adding in you question an example of desired input and output would help us to propose you a solution :-)

Neither your function nor your mapping seem particularly well thought out.

{ doesn't move the cursor to "the beginning of the paragraph" but to the first empty line above the current paragraph so you can get rid of that step as it doesn't help at all:
" Move to the beginning of the paragraph
normal! {

The next line makes it redundant anyway.

Selecting the current paragraph and then yanking it in two steps is wasteful. You can simply do:
normal! yip

instead of:
" Select the entire paragraph (only the current paragraph)
normal! vip
" Copy the selected text to the register
normal! y


You can use getreg('"') directly instead of wasting a variable:
let latex_block = 'yadda' . getreg('"') . 'yadda'

and that latex_block, too, is only used once, so why not simply:
execute "normal! A" . 'yadda' . getreg('"') . 'yadda'


normal! A starts insert mode already so there is no need to do normal! i before. That's a recipe for weird behaviors.

This comment is wrong and I'm not sure why you are doing }, here, as it puts the cursor on the first empty line after the current paragraph:
" Return to normal mode for the next action
normal! }


And :help q is a very useful command that you should probably refrain from overriding.


Here is a better, as in "more canonical" and "simpler", approach…

The usual method for wrapping the text covered by a given motion with arbitrary text is the following:
c<motion>foo<C-r>"bar<Esc>

where:

c<motion> cuts the text covered by <motion> to the unnamed register (") and enters insert mode,
foo inserts the text foo,
<C-r>" inserts the content of the unnamed register,
bar inserts the text bar,
<Esc> leaves insert mode.

For example:
cipyadda<C-r>yadda<Esc>


Since the whole point of the exercise is to not type that arbitrary text every time, you can easily turn that command into a mapping without resorting to a convoluted function:
nnoremap <key> cip\begin{otherlanguage}{american}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{<C-r>"}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn<Esc>



Going the function way may be useful if you want more flexibility, but the problem at hand is too simple to warrant it.

Paragraphs vs. paragraphs
I believe your implementation is off because of subtle differences between the { and } motions and the ip text object.
What Vim considers a paragraph can be found in :help paragraph.
Among other things, it says

Note that a blank line (only containing white space) is NOT a paragraph
boundary.

But this is contrasted with an exception in :help ip:

Exception: a blank line (only containing white space)
is also a paragraph boundary.

Considering the following text, pressing V} will select Visual paragraphs 2 and 3 while Vip will select only 2.
1. First paragraph.

2. There cursor is *here* and
there's whitespace after this paragraph.
<space>     
3. There's no whitespace after this one.

4. A final paragraph.

I was surprised, myself.
In fact, I've written such a long answer to come to terms with it.
And what LaTeX considers a paragraph is a completely different story.
Let's agree that it's irrelevant for this answer.
I strongly assume that you have whitespace-only lines in your LaTeX file which makes } and vip behave in surprising ways.
You can make them visible with :set list.
The usual way to get rid of them is a simple :%s/^\s\+$//.
A simple mapping
Instead of a function, you can use a simple mapping or a macro to achieve your goal.
Except, you can't record macros because that's what q does and you mapped it to put some LaTeX code in your buffer.
That's fine if you never ever use q but sooner or later, you may.
You can use a function key or any key prefixed with your leader key.
See :help leader.
As I understand your problem, you are dealing with complete paragraphs.
Putting a line with \begin{otherlanguage}... before your paragraph and one with }\end{otherlanguage} after it would solve your problem.
That's what the following mapping does:
:nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>q {o\begin{otherlanguage}{american}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{<Esc>}O}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn<Esc>}

This will ...

jump to the start of the current paragraph with {
start Insert mode in a new line with o
enter all that text up to <Esc>
jump after the end of the paragraph with }
start Insert mode in a new line above with O
enter all that text up to <Esc>
jump after the end of the paragraph with }

There's no command to jump to the beginning of the next paragraph, sadly.
Unless you have excessive empty lines, you could just append a j to the mapping to go one line down.
You might also do a search for the next non-whitespace character /[^\s]<CR
I believe this simple mapping should solve the problem at hand.
It's a buffer-local mapping and meant to be active only in LaTeX buffers.
Put it in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/latex.vim.
Newenvironment?
It's off-topic here and beyond the scope of this answer but doesn't LaTeX offer you a very convenient way to add new environments to have two short lines instead of whatever you want to add.
My LaTeX is very rusty and I didn't test it but shouldn't you be able to do something like:
\newenvironment{MyOtherLanguage}%
{\beginotherlanguage{american}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande}%
{\endotherlanguage\switchcolumn}


I would propose:
nnoremap <expr> q 'yyPI\begin{otherlanguage}{american}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{' . "\<Esc>" . 'A}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn' . "\<Esc>j0"

Where:

yy yank/copy the current line (I believe paragraph in your case)
P put the copied line in front
I\begin.. insert the text in front of the line/paragraph
"<Esc>" leaves insert mode
"A\end.." insert the text at the end of the line/paragraph
"<Esc>" leaves insert mode
j0 go to the start of the next line/pargraph


Another answer in the low quality queue. This would probably not happen (and be more helpful to OP) if there was a little bit of supporting information as to how this addresses OP's problem.
